# If devas do not have gross bodies, does that mean they do not experience material sensations?

Tags: gods, philosophy, body

If it is true that devas do not have gross bodies but only causal and subtle bodies, does that mean that they do not experience material sensations or desires? Are there any assertions in scripture or any scholars that state that devas do not experience material sensations or desires?

Now do not just answer me with quotes that describe devas as experiencing material sensations, as words may take on different meanings in different contexts, but please answer me with quotes addressing the question directly.

Comment: even subtle bodies can feel sensations. otherwise what is the point of 'enjoyments' in svarg lok, or 'punishments' in narak ? subtle bodies are much stronger, they can withstand lot of pain and pleasure without "dying".

Comment: @mar But do the devas have material enjoyments? Or purely intellectual enjoyments?

Comment: Also, don't the dwellers in heaven and hell have gross bodies? I'm not talking about the devas, but about the ordinary people there.

Comment: no. everyone has only subtle bodies. there are 2 layers of material bodies - gross & subtle - both are material.gross - on earth. subtle - everywhere else. only atma/soul is spiritual - that is observable after mukti/moksha.

Comment: You're saying that everyone in svarg lok and naraka have only subtle bodies and do not have gross bodies?

Comment: @mar Yes, but although the subtle body is, by comparison, more material and less spiritual than the atman, it is also, by comparison, less material and more spiritual than the gross body, right? So while the subtle body is not spiritual in comparison with the atman, it is spiritual in comparison with the gross body.

Comment: yes . gross < subtle < atma